# On option select angularJS not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selection

**Scenario** - Following is my `HTML` code for select box which on selecting `Every Day` option suppose to open a div with `Everyday` selected and select day select option starting from 2.

**Problem** - Though the div is opening correctly but **Every Day** option is not `pre selected` and day select drop down is also not starting from 2 like I believe it should.

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**HTML Code** -

```
<div>
    <select
        id="repeatval"
        ng-model="event.repeat"
        ng-options="repeat.value as repeat.name for repeat in repeats"
        ng-init="event.repeat = event.repeat || repeats[0].value"
        class="btn">
    </select>
</div>
<div ng-if="event.repeat === 2">
    <input type="radio" name="everyday" ng-model="event.everyday" value="forever" ng-checked="true" /> Everyday
    <input type="radio" name="everyday" ng-model="event.everyday" value="dayselval" />
    Select <select
            id="selday"
            ng-model="event.selday"
            ng-options="day.value as day.name for day in days"
            ng-init="event.day = event.day || days[0].value"
            class="btn">
           </select> Day
    <input type="radio" name="everyday" ng-model="event.everyday" value="pickdate" /> Pick a date
</div>
```

**Plnkr** - [PLNKR DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jMFLvP9MGhzkXE5sMJ7W?p=preview)

**EDIT** -

Ad per Vamsi comment- I solved the selection problem by applying -

`ng-init="event.selday = event.day || days[0].value"`

Changed `event.day` to `event.selday`

Comment: `event.selday` is not initialized, that's why it is not showing

Comment: @VamsiV 50% solved..thx for the help..50% still left :)

Comment: You should also initialize the event object: `$scope.event = { repeat: 2 };`

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan Your code is making "Every Day" selected by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want make input radio pre selected you can set `ng-value="forever"`

For selecting the option you must set the ng-model value, in your case the value is not selected and you can do this with ng-init like this:

```
 Select <select
                id="selday"
                ng-init="event.selday = 2"
                ng-model="event.selday"
                ng-options="day.value as day.name for day in days"
                ng-init="event.day = event.day || days[0].value"
                class="btn">
               </select> Day
```